# How to use a digital potentiometer to control current

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, potentiometer

I am attempting to rig an RC Car's rear wheels to an arduino.

Initially I attempted to just hook it into the powered digital pins but after MUCH headache I realized I wasn't getting enough current.

SO I decided to use a digital potentiometer instead.

The plan is to hook the 5v from the arduino (which when used by itself runs the wheels so it IS providing enough current) to the bread board.

Then use the potentiometer to control the 5v flow to the wheels.

I for the life of me can't get this hooked up though.

I am using the below potentiometer along with [the Arduino Uno R3](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11021)

[image]

[The datasheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/22060b.pdf)

[image]

Comment: A digital pot is the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: @MattYoung okay though informative not useful. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Why not PWM through a Darlington?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you please link to what you are referring to. I am obviously a nub lol

Comment: The digital pot isn't wrong, but it can't have the current going through it directly: it could control a current source. However, that is going to be wasteful because it amounts to linear regulation. PWM is indeed the efficient way to control the average current to motors or other devices which don't mind being rapidly pulsed. And it is relatively easy to implement since it involves only full on and off behavior of the output device.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Arduino-with-TIP120-transistor-to-control-moto/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams just overnighted 5 of them from Amazon. thanks for the insight.

Comment: Don't forget the diodes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams good looking out! Just got 25 of those too lol

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you make this an answer so I can select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a digipot to control an analog voltage, consider using PWM to turn a Darlington transistor on and off very quickly. It will be more efficient, use fewer parts, and be cheaper overall.

["Use Arduino with TIP120 transistor to control motors and high power devices"](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Arduino-with-TIP120-transistor-to-control-moto/)

Answer (score 2):

You can design a Voltage-Controlled-Current-Source (VCCS). One way to do it is by using op-amps to build a transconductance amplifier, like transimpedance amplifier only the opposite. Here's one type of circuit that can let you do that.

In this Bilateral Current Source circuit, you can make R1 controllable with the potentiometer.

[image]

[Taken from Texas Instruments App Notes 31](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf)

Comment: Note: This answer focuses on the question asked "How to use a digital potentiometer to control current"